# Questions about a research paper on salient region detection and segmentation

Tags: math, computer-vision, k-means, image-scaling, hill-climbing

I am reading [this](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Estrider/publications/AES_ICVS08.pdf) paper in an attempt to recreate the salient region detection and segmentation model employed. I have the following questions pertaining to section 3 of the paper and I would highly appreciate it if someone could provide clarity on them.

1. The word "scales" is used at multiple points in the section, for example, line 4 of the section states "saliency maps are created at different scales". I do not exactly understand what the authors mean by the word scales. Moreover, is there a mathematical way to think about it?
2. I understand that a saliency value [image] is computed for each pixel at ([image]) using the equation [image]

However, there is no mention of [image] in the equation. Hence, I am confused as to what pixel the saliency value is being computed for. Is it [image]?

3. I did not understand what the authors meant by the term "bin" in section 3.2 line 5 where it is stated, "The hill-climbing algorithm can be seen as a search window being run across the space of the d-dimensional histogram to find the largest bin within that window."

Lastly, any other tips or clarifications are most welcome and much appreciated!

Comment: In case you are unable to access the link to the research paper, the following citation may help: Achanta, R., Estrada, F., Wils, P., & Süsstrunk, S. (2008, May). Salient region detection and segmentation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming. Possibly belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com/,  if on topic there.

Comment: The questions here have already been answered [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/28740/2444), so I guess this post should be closed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has already an answer on another site and it's off-topic here.